# Collapsing Google spreadsheet cells into a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot figure out how to have one cell grouped to contain other cells that are expandable/collapsible.

What I am trying to do is have cell A1 contain "Stats" while cell A2, A3, A4, A5 be collapsible/expandable within cell A1.

Is this possible to do in Google Sheets?

So far the only thing that I can figure out, is to "hide" rows. Kind of a pain in the butt compared to Excel, however it guess it will work unless someone has a method that functions like Excel's.

Comment: Very much a pain.  Hiding seems to be google's answer to this, but the hiding is undone when you 'unhide'.  You must reselect the rows and then re-hide them.  If you have multiple levels of 'hiding' they are all unhidden at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This function was added to G Suite as of May 2018. Select a group of rows, right-click on them, and select "Group Rows ##-##".

[Google Documentation](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pm4Gd4O_Bm0)

The interface is a bit clunky, but it does work!

Comment: It's super clunky because it turns out that when you expand and collapse them, it syncs the expansion status to everyone else looking at the spreadsheet, and if they happen to have their cursor in that area, they get kicked out of it. :(

Comment: You are not wrong, @Trejkaz - it's a strong argument in favor of using Filter Views if you need to just "not see" content for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Google Apps Script-based substitute for native "row group" functionality that Excel has. After entering the script in Tools > Script Editor, you will get the new menu "Groups" next time after opening the spreadsheet.

The items are

- Hide Groups: all designated groups of rows are hidden
- Show Groups: all designated groups of rows are unhidden (each individual group of hidden rows can be unhidden by clicking it on the left edge of the sheet).
- Group Rows: creates a group of rows determined by the current selection. Use this option after selecting some range in the sheet (the columns don't matter, only the row span of the range is recorded).
- Ungroup Rows: removes a group (if a group with precisely that row span was created previously).
- Clear All Groups: removes all groups.

The script uses [DocumentProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store the group information (as a pair [first row, number of rows]), the `hideRows` / `showRows` methods to manipulate the rows, and `toast` method to display messages to the user.

Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Hide Groups", functionName: "hideGroups"},
              {name: "Show Groups", functionName: "showGroups"},
              {name: "Group Rows", functionName: "groupRows"},
              {name: "Ungroup Rows", functionName: "ungroupRows"},
              {name: "Clear All Groups", functionName: "clearAllGroups"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Groups", menu);
}

function groupRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var groups = JSON.parse(dp.getProperty("groups") || "[]");
  Logger.log(groups);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var group = [range.getRow(), range.getHeight()];
  if (groups.some(function (g) {
    return (g[0] == group[0]) && (g[1] == group[1]);
  })) {
    ss.toast("Group already exists");
  }
  else {
    groups.push(group);
    dp.setProperty("groups", JSON.stringify(groups));
    ss.toast("Group added");
  }
}

function ungroupRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var groups = JSON.parse(dp.getProperty("groups") || "[]");
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var group = [range.getRow(), range.getHeight()];
  var newGroups = groups.filter(function (g) {
    return (g[0] != group[0]) || (g[1] != group[1]);
  });
  if (newGroups.length == groups.length) {
    ss.toast("No such group");
  }
  else {
    dp.setProperty("groups", JSON.stringify(newGroups));
    ss.toast("Group removed");
  }
}

function hideGroups() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var groups = JSON.parse(dp.getProperty("groups") || "[]");
  for (var i in groups) {
    sheet.hideRows(groups[i][0], groups[i][1]);
  }
}

function showGroups() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var groups = JSON.parse(dp.getProperty("groups") || "[]");
  for (var i in groups) {
    sheet.showRows(groups[i][0], groups[i][1]);
  }
}

function clearAllGroups() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dp = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  dp.deleteProperty("groups");
  ss.toast("All groups removed");
}
```